# Configuring Xorg.conf for i915 intel driver

Tags: debian, xorg, intel-gma

I have a MotionComputing M1400 pen tablet. It runs Debian Squeeze, and today I noticed it was using software rendering for OpenGL, so I decided to try to use the `intel` driver. My chipset is the Intel 855GM. When I initially installed Debian, I had to modify xorg.conf so it would pick up my pen. That `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is [here](http://pastebin.com/MMWRYJBq). To install the driver, I added the ppa `ppa:glasen/intel-driver` and ran `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`. Upon reboot, my cursor is visible, but I'm sitting at a black screen. My cursor changes to a text selection cursor when I move it over certain parts of the screen, which seem to be the login prompt. I went into tty6 and stopped gdm3 with `/etc/init.d/gdm3 stop` and then tried `Xorg -configure`, which failed. [Here](http://pastebin.com/BMJjxzwM) is the log file it produced. I tried to combine the `xorg.conf.new` it created with my original `xorg.conf` into a new `xorg.conf`, which is [here](http://pastebin.com/r2BKRhvH), but that didn't work either. What should I do to get a graphical interface back?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to go with the ppa instead of the [Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xserver-xorg-video-intel)?  There's also a backport of a newer version, 2.15.0.

Comment: When I use the Debian package, it falls back to software rendering, as reported by `glxinfo`.

Comment: I'd give the backport a try [(instructions)](http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/).

Comment: The backport did the trick. Thanks, @sr_ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is strongly recommended not using ppa's on other Debian-based systems, since those packages were meant for Ubuntu-only distributions.** That said, there are different ways you can update your packages.

### 1. Backport

You can backport your package as said sr_ with the provided [instructions](http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/).

### 2. Use `unstable` repositories

This was already explained [here](/a/8051/41104).

### 3. Build from Debian source

You can get the most recent driver from the [Debian package page](http://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/xserver-xorg-video-intel) and build it yourself (you can search the source using `http://packages.debian.org/src:package_name`). Just download the `.dsc`, `orig.tar.gz`, and `diff.gz` (the package may not include that last one) in a single directory and execute `dpkg-source -x package_version-revision.dsc`. It will build a nice .deb file that you can install using `dpkg -i`. Be sure that you have all the build dependencies using `apt-get build-dep package_name` and your source repositories activated in the `sources.list` file.

### 4. Building from Debian-git

Using the same package list as above, look for the "Debian Package Source Repository" section, and clone the repository (you must know how to use git). Enter in the just created directory and run `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc`, you can also modify the source and apply patches. In the parent directory there will be your recently created .deb packages.

### 5. Building from the upstream

This is more complex to achieve since each piece of software has its own way of building/installing, but in most cases involve:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/something ## The prefix indicates where to install so you can delete it later and it won't mess with your systems' installed packages.
make
make install
```

You must consult the documentation in those cases.

You can debianize this package too, using [dh_make](http://man.he.net/man8/dh_make).